# Point Cloud View Perspective Transformation

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, point-clouds

Suppose a point cloud is defined as a set of points in an Nx3 matrix [x1, y1, z1; x2, y2, z2; xN, yN, zN] where each row determines the position of each point, and a position vector is defined by [xC, yC, zC, rhoC, thetaC, phiC] where the first 3 entries denote the position of the camera and the last 3 entries determine the pitch, roll, and yaw. As the position vector changes, is there a linear operation to transform the point cloud matrix to display its correct corresponding view? Is there a way to compute the change in position of the pointcloud and it's change in pitch, roll and yaw?

Comment: The matrix to transform the pointclouds with is the inverse of the matrix that transforms the old camera position to the new position. This can easily be done with the help of the principal vectors. Is that what you want to do? What part do you need help with?

Comment: How do you deal with the fact the camera is really a person's head and the head location in 3D space is in terms of units, say meters, but the screen location of the points is in pixels?

Comment: You did not mention that there are different coordinate systems. So if the points are given in pixels, what does the z-coordinate mean? I guess you don't have access to the original positions of the points in world space?

Comment: No I do not have access to the original world points.

Comment: So what do you have? It's still unclear to me. The positions of the projected points on a screen?